# Is there any way to speed up my NUMBA implementation of sparse matrix multiplication?

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, numba

NUMBA does not support sparse matrix and I would like to find a way to write my own function for spM multiplication in COO format.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, prange
from numba.core.types import ListType, int32, DictType, float64
from numba.typed import Dict, List
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix

LIST_TYPE_TRIP = ListType(int32)
DICT_TYPE_TRIP = DictType(keyty=int32, valty=float64)
TOLERANCE = 1e-6

@njit
def triplet2lookup(bc: np.ndarray, m: int) -> tuple[np.ndarray, np.ndarray]:
    """
    :param bc: column index of sparse matrix b
    :param m: num of cols in sparse matrix b
    :return:
    """
    table = np.zeros((m, m), dtype=np.int32)
    count = np.zeros(m, dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(len(bc)):
        val = bc[i]
        table[val, count[val]] = i
        count[val] += 1
    return table, count


@njit(fastmath=True)
def _mul(ar, ac, av, br, bc, bv, an, bm):
    na = len(av)
    rr = np.empty(len(ar) * 2, dtype=np.int32)
    rc = np.empty(len(rr), dtype=np.int32)
    rv = np.empty(len(rr))
    table, count = triplet2lookup(bc, bm)
    cnt = 0
    hash_mat = np.zeros((an, bm))
    for i in range(na):
        target = ac[i]
        for j in range(count[target]):
            row_idx = ar[i]
            col_idx = br[table[target, j]]
            rr[cnt] = row_idx
            rc[cnt] = col_idx
            rv[cnt] = av[i] * bv[table[target, j]]
            cnt += 1
            if hash_mat[row_idx, col_idx] < TOLERANCE:
                rr[cnt] = row_idx
                rc[cnt] = col_idx
                rv[cnt] = av[i] * bv[table[target, j]]
                cnt += 1
            else:
                rv[cnt] += av[i] * bv[table[target, j]]
            if cnt >= len(rr):
                rr, rc, rv = extend_arr(rr, rc, rv)

    rr = rr[:cnt]
    rc = rc[:cnt]
    rv = rv[:cnt]
    return rr, rc, rv


@njit
def _extend_arr(rr, dtype):
    tmp_rr = np.empty(len(rr) * 2, dtype=dtype)
    tmp_rr[:len(rr)] = rr
    return tmp_rr


@njit
def extend_arr(rr, rc, rv):
    rr = _extend_arr(rr, np.int32)
    rc = _extend_arr(rc, np.int32)
    rv = _extend_arr(rv, np.float64)
    return rr, rc, rv
```

After comparing the speed against scipy, I found scipy is much faster for big matrices.

```
n = 50000
m = 1000
row_a = np.random.randint(0, m, n)
col_a = np.random.randint(0, m, n)
val_a = np.random.random(n)

row_b = np.random.randint(0, m, n)
col_b = np.random.randint(0, m, n)
val_b = np.random.random(n)

a_sci = coo_matrix((val_a, (row_a, col_a)), shape=(m, m))
b_sci = coo_matrix((val_b, (row_b, col_b)), shape=(m, m))
%timeit scipy_res = a_sci @ b_sci
# 21.4 ms ± 722 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%timeit rr, rc, rv = _mul(row_a, col_a, val_a, col_b, row_b, val_b, m, m)
202 ms ± 47 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

On my machine, scipy is almost 10 times faster. So I wonder if there is any thing like SIMD or parallel computation that can be applied to speed up the _mul function?

I have tried to parallelize the _mul function by changing @njit to @njit(parallel=True) and range -> prange for either inner or outer loops but it slows down the algorithm.

Comment: Is this algorithm correct? When I take the sum of the output of the scipy method with `scipy_res.sum()`, it is different from the sum of the ouput of your method with `coo_matrix((rv, (rr, rc)), shape=(m, m)).sum()`, or even `rv.sum()`. If it's not correct, there's no point in worrying about speed.

Comment: SciPy seems to implement COO @ COO by first converting both arguments to CSR. You might be able to get better speed by converting to CSR and doing the multiply in CSR. This seems to be where CSR matrix multiply is implemented: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/03dea39c161729eeb243cecca0dbb2fdd2e130eb/scipy/sparse/sparsetools/csr.h#L608

Comment: `if hash_mat[row_idx, col_idx] < TOLERANCE:` Since `hash_mat` is always zero, this check is always true. The `else` is unreachable.

Comment: Good sparse multiplication methods were developed by mathematicians years ago (1990s) for CSR (or CSC) formats.  If I recall it's 2 step process, first determining the size of the returned arrays, and the filling in the values in newly created arrays.

Comment: Why not using a dedicated BLAS library? https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/docs/onemkl/developer-reference-c/2024-0/cblas-gemm-001.html#GUID-97718E5C-6E0A-44F0-B2B1-A551F0F164B2 Or directly the scipy implementation?

Comment: Keep in mind that with the most common implementations, the COO to CSR conversion does two things - it sorts the nonzero elements,, lexically by column and rows.  And it sums duplicate entries.  In general COO coordinates can be in any order.  The scipy version does not try to implement any sort of indexing in the COO format, and math is done in the CSR format.  COO is convenient for user input, but not most math operations.

Comment: @NickODell I confirm the result is identical to scipy. Make sure to use rr, rc, rv = _mul(row_a, col_a, val_a, col_b, row_b, val_b, m, m), wherefor matrix b, the order is col, row, val.

Comment: @NickODell Thanks a lot for pointing out that scipy implements the multiplication in CSR format.

Comment: @hpaulj I do understand that sparse matrix multiplication is not a trivial task and requires years of experience exploring the algorithm and hardware architectures to device an efficient algorithm. But in my case, I have a simulation project done in NUMBA and all functions are required to be written in NUMBA. That is why I am looking for a quick implementation. I did not expect to outperform scipy/blas/lapack. But I am aiming to get closer.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a fairly simple way of doing this which is only 15% slower than SciPy, and still allows you to use nopython mode. The basic idea is to call SciPy's matrix multiply.

If you do this in the most direct way, using `@jit(forceobj=True)`, it has a problem: any function which calls `_mul()` cannot determine its return type, and therefore cannot be run in nopython mode. Any function that calls that function cannot be run in nopython mode, etc.

I tried working around this, by specifying the return type with a signature, but I couldn't figure out how to get `njit()` functions to be able to use it. Eventually, I found `nb.objmode()`, which can specify a block of code which is allowed to run Python functions within a broader Numba function. Functions which call this function can still be marked with `njit()`.

```
import numba as nb

@nb.njit()
def mul2(ar, ac, av, br, bc, bv, n):
    with nb.objmode(row='i4[:]', col='i4[:]', data='f8[:]'):
        a_sci = coo_matrix((av, (ar, ac)), shape=(n, n))
        b_sci = coo_matrix((bv, (br, bc)), shape=(n, n))
        result = (a_sci @ b_sci).tocoo()
        row = result.row
        col = result.col
        data = result.data
    return row, col, data
```

Warning: The documentation for [objmode](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/withobjmode.html) says that there is usually a better way of accomplishing your goals than using objmode. There may be a better way of doing this - I don't have a lot of experience in Numba.

Why is this slower than calling SciPy directly? The problem is that you want the result in COO format, but the matrix multiply produces results in CSR format. Converting takes extra time.

I also experimented with an option that outputs in CSR.

```
@nb.njit()
def mul3(ar, ac, av, br, bc, bv, n):
    with nb.objmode(data='f8[:]', indptr='i4[:]', indices='i4[:]'):
        a_sci = coo_matrix((av, (ar, ac)), shape=(n, n))
        b_sci = coo_matrix((bv, (br, bc)), shape=(n, n))
        result = a_sci @ b_sci
        data = result.data
        indptr = result.indptr
        indices = result.indices
    return data, indices, indptr
```

This version is only 2% slower than the direct SciPy option.

These functions benefit from the optimized algorithms present in SciPy, while being able to be called from Numba functions that use nopython mode for all other operations.

Timings:

```
Pure SciPy
27.8 ms ± 471 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Original Numba
184 ms ± 594 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

Numba SciPy COO output
32 ms ± 228 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

Numba SciPy CSR output
28.3 ms ± 685 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```